# How to properly wait for AE converged in android's Camera 2 API?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have read the documentation and beautiful tables from page https://source.android.com/devices/camera/camera3_3Amodes and I'm wondering how to properly wait for AE/AWB to be converged. Should I post only one request with `session.capture` and read it's states during `onCaptureProgressed`? Or should I call `session.setRepeating` and read it's states during each request cycle(start, complete)?